# What does stopping the runtime while uploading a dataset to Hub cause?

Tags: database, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence, hub

I am getting the following error while trying to upload a dataset to [Hub (dataset format for AI)](https://github.com/activeloopai/Hub) `S3SetError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "<...>".`

So, I tried to delete the dataset and it is throwing this error below.

`CorruptedMetaError: 'boxes/tensor_meta.json' and 'boxes/chunks_index/unsharded' have a record of different numbers of samples. Got 0 and 6103 respectively.`

Using Hub version: v2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like when you were uploading the dataset the runtime got interrupted which led to the corruption of the data you were trying to upload. Using `force=True` while deleting should allow you to delete it.

For more information feel free to check out the Hub API basics docs for details on how to [delete datasets in Hub](https://docs.activeloop.ai/api-basics#deleting-datasets).

If you stop uploading a Hub dataset midway through your dataset will be only partially uploaded to Hub. So, you will need to restart the upload. If you would like to re-create the dataset, you can use the `overwrite = True` flag in `hub.empty(overwrite = True)`. If you are making updates to an existing dataset, you should use version control to checkpoint the states that are in good shape.